# Is there any guidance or evidence about the use of contrasting colours for title vs body text of a webpage

Tags: website-design, typography, graphic-design

Is there any guidance or evidence suggesting whether it is better* within the body of a webpage to have titles (and subtitles) in a contrasting colour to the body text? Does this improve readability of the page, or is it purely a design choice?

- by better, I mean easier for a user to scan / read a page and determine the key concepts described.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @Paparazzi ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "contrasting colour"? or do you just mean "a different colour"?

Comment: @Splatz yes, just a different colour.

Answer (score 2):

Solid understanding of typography may help you because there is more than one way to improve readability and make it easier to scan the page.

The following article has some examples which illustrate how use of colour, font size, font case, spacing above and below, etc can all help titles and subtitles to stand out (this helps you to scan):

http://retinart.net/typography/typographicscale/

Also the text you use for your titles and subtitles plays a big part in the readability too.